# error in packet, no such name: when using snmpset in php

Tags: php, snmp

I am doing an snmpset by using php language, I want to set the interface to the 'up' status. So I need to set it to '1' value.

When I am doing snmpget, it works and returns INTEGER: 2 (this means that the interface is down):

```
$get_val = snmpget($host, $community, $oid);
echo $get_val;
```

But when I am doing the snmpset, I have an error with the oid:

> Warning: snmpset(): Error in packet at 'iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.7':
>   (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB

```
snmpset($host, $community, $oid, $type, $value);
```

The host is: "IP:PORT"

the community is: "community_string"

the oid is: "1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.7"

the type is: "i"

the value is:  1

The problem is that the same oid is working in the snmpget but invalid in the snmpset.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears `oid` is expecting bytes, not string.

Comment: @Zanderwar I tried to convert the oid from string to bytes and it doesnt work.